# Numerical integration of Differential Equations with complex coefficients with the Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

I have a question about solving differential equations with complex coefficients numerically. I have a DE of the form:

$$
x^{'}(t) = f(x,t)
$$
where the right-hand-side is a function with complex coefficients. For example: $$f(x,t) = (i\gamma + \alpha)x$$ Now I want to write code to solve it with the Euler method. The problem is, I dont want to implement complex numbers in C++ and want to solve it in terms of real and imaginary part.
With the Euler formula being:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n + dt \cdot f(x_n,t_n)
$$
how can I seperate Real and imaginary parts?
I had the idea of doing solving it this way:
$$
Re(x_{n+1}) = Re(x_n) + dt \cdot Re(f(x_n,t_n))
$$
and
$$
Im(x_{n+1}) = Im(x_n) + dt \cdot Im(f(x_n,t_n))
$$
Is this the right way? Maybe it's easy but I'm just missing some details. How would you do it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the explicit Euler method, you need to replace $f(x, t)$ by $f(x_n, t_n)$. Also programmatically, you'll face the problem of how $f()$ is implemented. Remember that the parameter $x_n$ is a complex number.

Comment: Just edited my question. I forgot the acutal dependancies of f(x,t). @Gribouillis Can't I just write the ODE as a ODE System with Real- and Imaginary Part and a Matrix?

Comment: If $f$ is as simple as in the example, you can write it with a matrix, but this is a very special case.